# How to disable an "always there" program if it isn't in the processes list?

Tags: process, crashplan

I have Crashplan and it is constantly running in the background and making backups every 15 minutes. It caused some problems with the backup target folders, so I want it to be inactive while I am making changes to these folders.

I started the application itself, but could not find some kind of "Pause" button. So I decided to just stop its process. I first tried the lazy way - the system monitor in the Gnome panel has a "Processes" tab - but didn't find it listed there. Then I did a `sudo ps -A` and read through the whole list.

I don't recognize everything on the list (many process names are self-explaining, like evolution-alarm, but I don't recognize others like phy0) but there was nothing which sounded even remotely like crashplan. But I know that there must have been a process belonging to Crashplan running at this time, because the main Crashplan window was open when I ran the command.

Do you have any advice how to stop this thing from running? The best solution would involve temporary preventing it from loading on boot too, since I may need to reboot while doing the maintenance there.

Comment: A process that runs repeatedly but doesn't appear in the process list may well be using cron/anacron to schedule itself. Look in `/etc/cron*` for clues. (I don't know anything about Crashplan specifically).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Crashplan website it looks like it should be starting a process from /etc/init.d at bootup. I would look in /etc/init.d to see if there are any startup scripts that look like they are for Crashplan. You can easily temporarily prevent a startup script from running at boot time by running:

```
sudo update-rc.d script-name disable
```

Where script-name is the name of the script you see in /etc/init.d that you want to disable. It can be re-enabled later by running:

```
sudo update-rc.d script-name enable
```

This will put things back the way they were before you disabled the script.

Also, the website says you can stop crashplan temporarily by running:

```
sudo /usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanEngine stop
```

The path is dependent on where you installed crashplan and will probably only stop the currently running process.

One last thing. I find that ps -ax provides more information than ps -A and can be useful when trying to find a running process, especially when the output is piped to grep. If I were looking for a process associated with crashplan I would try a command like this:

```
ps -ax | grep Crash
```

I hope this helps!